# The import org.opencv.highgui cannot be resolved

Tags: java, opencv

I installed OpenCV (opencv-3.0.0-alpha) and it works proberly but I can't use that import

```
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//      System.loadLibrary("opencv_java244");
//      Mat m = Highgui.imread("C:/Users/raj/Desktop/sa1.png",
//              Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
//      new LoadImage("C:/Users/raj/Desktop/dst1.jpg", m);
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
The import org.opencv.highgui cannot be resolved
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### in opencv3.0, there is no more highgui module in java.

the functionality was split up into new videoio and imgcodecs (that's where you will find imread) modules.

since there is no gui available from java, - no need to have a highgui module anymore.

```
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs; // imread, imwrite, etc
import org.opencv.videoio;   // VideoCapture
```

Comment: ++C ofc still has it. ;)

Comment: I don't know how I feel about this... except: 
OpenCV != Consistency

Comment: true, - atm, they don't seem to fear breaking things.. there will be definitely more surprises, like the drawing calls all went into imgproc, constants changed their name overnight, it's a bit like they're playing pranks on you ;)

Comment: what can i do if i want to use following  in android                                          org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;

Comment: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class imgcodecs
  location: package org.opencv

Comment: OLD CODE: Highgui.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem); NEW CODE: Imgcodecs.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs; // imread, imwrite
```

Not: org.opencv.imgcodecs;

`Core.line`, `Core.Rectangle`, `Core.imread`, `Core.imwrite` deprecated.

Use `Imgcodecs.imread`, `Imgcodecs.imwrite`, etc.