# Java implementation of Opencv (3.0.0) template matching

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0, highgui, matchtemplate

I want to match a template (small image) in a given picture using Opencv.

I found the following code from this port: [OpenCV Template Matching example in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001083/opencv-template-matching-example-in-android)

The problem is starting openvc 3.0.0, highgui is broken down into new videoio and imgcodecs and the code below is using highgui.

```
package opencv;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Core.MinMaxLocResult;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

class MatchingDemo {
    public void run(String inFile, String templateFile, String outFile, int match_method) {
        System.out.println("\nRunning Template Matching");

        Mat img = Highgui.imread(inFile);
        Mat templ = Highgui.imread(templateFile);

        // / Create the result matrix
        int result_cols = img.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
        int result_rows = img.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
        Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

        // / Do the Matching and Normalize
        Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, match_method);
        Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

        // / Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
        MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);

        Point matchLoc;
        if (match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF || match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
            matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
        } else {
            matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
        }

        // / Show me what you got
        Core.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),
                matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));

        // Save the visualized detection.
        System.out.println("Writing "+ outFile);
        Highgui.imwrite(outFile, img);

    }
}

public class TemplateMatching {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java246");
        new MatchingDemo().run(args[0], args[1], args[2], Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, that's an easy one ;) Imgcodecs.imwrite(...),  Imgcodecs.imread(...), Imgproc.rectangle(...) (as far as i can se right now)

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV 3.0.0 doesn't have Highui anymore. Use Imgcodecs.imread instead.

Follow this link.

[The import org.opencv.highgui cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890322/the-import-org-opencv-highgui-cannot-be-resolved)

Answer (score 2):

Read-write functions were moved from `org.opencv.highgui.Highgui` to `org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs`.
Drawing functions were moved from `org.opencv.core.Core` to `org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc`.
So the source becomes:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Core.MinMaxLocResult;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

class MatchingDemo {
    public void run(String inFile, String templateFile, String outFile,
            int match_method) {
        System.out.println("\nRunning Template Matching");

        Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(inFile);
        Mat templ = Imgcodecs.imread(templateFile);

        // / Create the result matrix
        int result_cols = img.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
        int result_rows = img.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
        Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

        // / Do the Matching and Normalize
        Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, match_method);
        Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

        // / Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
        MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);

        Point matchLoc;
        if (match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF
                || match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
            matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
        } else {
            matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
        }

        // / Show me what you got
        Imgproc.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),
                matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));

        // Save the visualized detection.
        System.out.println("Writing " + outFile);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite(outFile, img);

    }
}

public class TemplateMatching {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java300");
        new MatchingDemo().run(args[0], args[1], args[2], Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF);
    }

}
```